# Is it possible to specify a runtime dependency of a code generator?

Tags: npm, code-generation

I am working on an npm package that is used as a CLI to generate code. It makes sense that this project should generally be used as a `devDependency`.

But the generated code will require a third-party library at runtime. Is there a way to manage this dependency via `package.json`? I have seen other libraries include a note in the README that defines this dependency, but there is no guarantee that the end user will read this README, so I would like to be able to enforce this.

One thought I had was to use a `preinstall` script to validate that this third-party library was already installed, otherwise throw an error and don't allow the user to install. But that feels like more of a hack than a solution.

I anticipate someone saying "but won't it be obvious when none of the generated code works?" which is absolutely correct, but ideally this process should fail well before runtime.

I am not sure the specifics really matter here, but my package generates boilerplate TypeScript code for an API project, from an OpenAPI spec, and depends on Express.js at runtime.

Comment: Is the third-party library something that is available on npm?

Comment: Yes, it is Express.js.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a peer dependency. You can specify a peer dependency in `package.json` with [the `peerDependencies` key](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies).

In `npm` 6, missing peer dependencies will result in a warning.

In `npm` 7, missing peer dependencies are installed.